# Why doesn't my class override the universal asterisk selector?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I'm trying to write a new class to apply 10px margin to a div like this:

```css
.generic-form-filters {
  margin: 10px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="SearchFormWrapper" class="generic-form-filters m-height-650-above-tablet">
  Some code
</div>
```

However my `generic-form-filters` class does not work. I can see this in the Chrome console:
[image]

But I cannot find `generic-form-filters` class applied. How can I override `*`? I've checked that the minified CSS file contains `.generic-form-filters{margin:10px}`.

Edit 0: there were typos in class name `generic-form-filter`, I've corrected them to `generic-form-filters`.

Edit 1: I think it's the problem of nested classes, I can see it not working in this minimal example

https://jsfiddle.net/81Lzmwcn/2/

Comment: I converted your code to a live demo … and it does. So whatever the problem is, the cause of it isn't expressed in your question. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0tprnubx/ it works (as should be, since `*` has the lowest specificity). Maybe you have an error in one of the rules before `.generic-form-filter` (e.g. a missing `}` somewhere)?

Comment: it should work - as i see in your question you missed 's' at some place so please make sure you define the css and class name properly.

Comment: @SumitPatel Apologize, it's a typo, I've edited the question.

Comment: "Edit: there were typos in class name generic-form-filter, I've corrected them to generic-form-filters" — Did that fix the problem?

Comment: @Quentin No, I'm trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see that you are using sass (scss) for css preprocessing. Did you recompile the scss file to css after making the changes?

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of research I found the problem is because of nested classes, rather than universal selector. The fact is, `generic-form-filters` class was never applied. Here is a minimal example to describe the original code caused the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/81Lzmwcn/2/

The margin was added after I added `<div class="generic-form">` outside:

https://jsfiddle.net/k6ewas4j/1/